# Looking for a way to create a 24/7 repeating action in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, broadcast

I'm making an app that every 5 minutes it makes a **Wifi Scan** (and does some irrelevant stuff with that data)

I have tried to make an infinite loop inside a Service and sleeping it for 5 min, but in some AOSP based roms (4.4, it's a known bug) it doesn't work well, so I need other way to accomplish it.

How can I create an "endless" repeating task? What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think you can using **AlarmManager** to repeat your work, here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).